# Cypher query warning give inconsistent result when fix

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run this query:

```
MATCH (n:test) with n limit 100
WITH DISTINCT n, keys(n) AS allKeys
UNWIND allKeys AS key
with n, 
    CASE
        WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN {column: 'title', value: collect(n[key])}
        WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN {column: 'keywords', value: collect(n[key])}
    END AS data
with n, data, collect(data.value) as values
RETURN n.id, apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([data.column, values]))
```

This query purpose is to find all the property with given prefix and group their value into an object with apoc. An example result would be like so: [image: Correct result]

My issue start when Cypher give me this warning: `This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.` with status code `Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.FeatureDeprecationWarning`
[image: This is the warning that I get when running the previous query]
Then I try to fix the query by adding the `key` to the `WITH` keyword, like so: `WITH n, key, CASE ...`
But now the value in my object (`collect(n[key])`) does not return all of the value anymore and only the last one. I guess the rest have been overrides. [image: Wrong result]

Does anyone knows how to fix this but still remove the warning?

EDIT: I found out that by changing `n` to `*` in the first query without the `key` added, I get the same wrong result. Also add pictures.

Comment: what is your version of Neo4j? Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently using 4.4.23 community edition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you could rewrite your query to something like this:

```
MATCH (n:test) with n limit 100 
WITH DISTINCT n, keys(n) AS allKeys
UNWIND allKeys AS key
WITH n, 
    // Note: in the original query you used the aggregation expression `collect` which made `key` an implicit grouping key.
    CASE
      WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN {column: 'title', value:n[key]}
      WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN {column: 'keywords', value:n[key]}
    END AS data
WITH n, data.column AS column, collect(data.value) as values
RETURN n.id, apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([column, values]))
```

The problem with your original query was that you used non-grouping keys outside of an aggregation expression, so called "implicit grouping keys". Prior to neo4j 5.0 we allowed implicit grouping keys, but as that can get very confusing it was removed in 5.0. You can read more about the confusion with implicit grouping keys here: https://opencypher.org/articles/2017/07/27/ocig1-aggregations-article/

So, let's take this step-by-step:

Assume that you have a single node:

```
CREATE (:test{`prop.title1`:"title1", `prop.title2`:"title2", `prop.keywords`:"hey!"})
```

After this part of the query:

```
MATCH (n:test) with n limit 100
WITH DISTINCT n, keys(n) AS allKeys
UNWIND allKeys AS key
```

You have:

| n | key | allKeys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n | "prop.title1" | ["prop.title1", "prop.title2", "prop.keywords"] |
| n | "prop.title2" | ["prop.title1", "prop.title2", "prop.keywords"] |
| n | "prop.keywords" | ["prop.title1", "prop.title2", "prop.keywords"]` |

Let's have a look at the next part of the original query:

```
with n, 
CASE
    WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN {column: 'title', value: collect(n[key])}
    WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN {column: 'keywords', value: collect(n[key])}
END AS data
```

the explicit grouping keys are the projected variables/properties that does not contain any aggregations - which in this case is `n`. That means that all other variables which are used outside of an aggregation expression are "implicit" grouping keys - in your case the implicit grouping key is `key`. Implicit grouping keys are no longer supported from 5.0. But, instead of adding it as an explicit grouping key, you can remove the aggregation expression "collect":

```
WITH n, 
     CASE
       WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN {column: 'title', value:n[key]}
       WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN {column: 'keywords', value:n[key]}
     END AS data
```

This would mean that we know have:

| n | data |
| --- | --- |
| n | {column: "title", value: "title1"} |
| n | {column: "title", value: "title2" } |
| n | {column: "keywords", value: "hey!"}` |

If you now look at the next part of the original query:

```
with n, data, collect(data.value) as values
```

You again have the aggregation expression `collect` with grouping keys `n` and `data`. But you don't want to group on the full `data` object, instead you want to collect all `data.values` grouped by `n` and `data.column`:

```
WITH n, data.column AS column, collect(data.value) as values
```

Which gives us:

| n | column | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n | "title" | ["title1", "title2"] |
| n | "keywords" | ["hey!"] |

I hope this made it a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated syntax on line 4 can be also done when you aggregate the data.values after you define the dictionary {column: , value:}

Thus, no need to do the collect in line 4 since it is a duplication of the collect in line 5 later on. Instead, define the columns in line 5 so that will be in line with what you want on line 6. See updated query below.

```
1 MATCH (n:test) with n limit 100
2 WITH DISTINCT n, keys(n) AS allKeys
3 UNWIND allKeys AS key
4 with n, 
    CASE
        WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN {column: 'title', value: n[key]}
        WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN {column: 'keywords', value: n[key]}
    END AS data
5 WITH n, data.column as columns, collect(data.value) as values  
6 RETURN n.id as id, apoc.map.fromPairs(collect([columns, values]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This simpler query may work for your use case:

```
MATCH (n:test) WITH n LIMIT 100
UNWIND KEYS(n) AS key
WITH n, key, CASE
  WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.title' THEN 'title'
  WHEN key STARTS WITH 'prop.keywords' THEN 'keywords'
  END AS type
WHERE type IS NOT NULL
WITH n, type, COLLECT(n[key]) AS values
RETURN n.id, apoc.map.fromPairs(COLLECT([type, values]))
```

The `WITH DISTINCT n, ...` clause did not do anything (and was deleted), since we already know from the preceding `MATCH` clause that all `n` values would be distinct.